# mondrian mdx - schema calculated member SUM of dynamically filtered member

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I want to make a schema calculated member which brings the `SUM` of a dynamically filtered dimension. The problem is I don't know what the filters are going to be. For example, the formula

```
Sum
(
  Filter
  (
    [SHOP].[SHOP].MEMBERS
   ,
    [Measures].[SALES] > 0
  )
 ,[Measures].[SALES]
)
```

brings me the `SUM` of Sales for all Shops that have Sales > 0. I want to be able to get the `SUM` Sales only for SHOP1 and SHOP2 and after that, ONLY for SHOP3 and SHOP4. How can I accomplish this in a fixed formula?

I found a function that seems to be what I want (EXISTING) but it's not supported by `mondrian`.

Comment: please provide the script using `EXISTING` - we should be able to find a different way of calculating things. Also are you able to provide an example of your desired results table?

Answer (score 1):

This is for only SHOP1 and SHOP2:

```
Sum
(
  Filter
  (
    {[SHOP].[SHOP].[SHOP1],[SHOP].[SHOP].[SHOP2]}
   ,
    [Measures].[SALES] > 0
  )
 ,[Measures].[SALES]
)
```

Comment: I want the SUM calculated member to dinamically make the computation only for the selected filters; I don't want to make 2 calculated members one for SHOP1 & 2 and the other for SHOP3 & 4.

Comment: ...so on the row for SHOP1 you would like to see the sum for {SHOP1 ,SHOP2} and on the row for SHOP3 you would like to see the sum for {SHOP3 ,SHOP4} etc. ?

Comment: No; This calculated member (measure) should bring the same result for all rows as follows: if I select SHOP 1 & 2 it should bring for both rows the SUM of SHOP 1 & 2; If I select SHOP 1, 2 & 4 it should bring for the three rows the SUM of SHOP 1, 2 & 4. So, the computation should be dynamic.

Comment: So SHOP is in the slicer? What do you have ON ROWS ? Can you supply your complete mdx script as it is not simple trying to understand your context - if you cannot add the complete script then a picture of the cellset would help